# When I hide a div it pushes the div below it up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a scroll down animation where the user clicks a button is scrolls down to a div and deletes the two divs above it. However, my problem is that the animation works fine on chrome but on firefox and safari the button actually make you scroll past the beginning of the div.

My desired output is https://wearebarbarian.com/

My JS:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#index"]', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top - 100
    }, 1200);
    $('.introsection').delay(1300).hide(0);
    $('#swipe-down').delay(1300).hide(0);
    $('body').css('overflowY', 'scroll');
    $('#home-mobile-nav').css('position', 'fixed');
    $('#home').css('margin-top', '0');
});
```

I think the problem is:

```
$('.introsection').delay(1300).hide(0);
    $('#swipe-down').delay(1300).hide(0);
```

is there a better way to hide the divs.

the codepen to my problem is https://codepen.io/mrsalami/pen/GBRmgx

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: For me it works the same in Chrome and Firefox, both seem to scroll further than you might have intended. Why do you scroll to `$($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top - 100`, where `this` is your button, when you can simply scroll to what you want to be at the top? You could also make better use of chaining your animation.

Comment: You scroll to the position of the 3rd div, *then* (after a delay) hide the two above it?  What would you **expect** to happen to the scroll position?

Comment: If you're trying to emulate (copy) the wearebarbarian site then note the scroll bar position - *it doesn't change*.  They are not scrolling the browser, they are moving the content.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-webkit-, -moz-` to the CSS to make the CSS specific for browser.
`-webkit-` is for Chrome and Safari and `-moz-` is for Firefox.
Only by defining specific CSS related to margin and padding, the design of the content can be maintain same through out the browser.